# What does "Resend original POST data to a new location" mean in sqlmap?

Tags: security, sql-injection, sqlmap

When using sqlmap, I have the following:

> sqlmap got a 302 redirect to 'http://localhost/sqlmap/index.php'. Do you want to follow? [Y/n] y

I understand that my POST response is redirecting to index.php. The next question is:

> redirect is a result of a POST request. Do you want to resend original POST data to a new location? [Y/n] y

But I don't understand what resending the origin data to a new location mean.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it's resending your POST data to the new location (redirect) found. Let's say your POST data is:

```
data = {
    "username": "example",
    "password": "example"
}
```

And you're sending it to `http://example.com/php?login=True` if the site redirects you to `http://example.com/php?login=False` it will resend the data to that link, so in a nutshell, sqlmap is going to retry the login credentials on the new link it's been redirected to.

---

Edited for confusion (see comments)

**POST**:

> In computing, POST is a request method supported by the HTTP protocol
>   used by the World Wide Web. By design, the POST request method
>   requests that a web server accept the data enclosed in the body of the
>   request message, most likely for storing it. It is often used when
>   uploading a file or when submitting a completed web form.

*Reference*: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)

**GET**:

> GET requests a representation of the specified resource. Note that GET
>   should not be used for operations that cause side-effects, such as
>   using it for taking actions in web applications. One reason for this
>   is that GET may be used arbitrarily by robots or crawlers, which
>   should not need to consider the side effects that a request should
>   cause.

*Reference*: [What is the difference between POST and GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get)

Comment: I think I understand. Is it safe to say that if my request is redirected to a GET after my POST request, it's useless to resend the data sent?

Comment: That would never happen because POST and GET are two different things, POST requires a spot to provide data, GET is only receiving data

Comment: So in my website's case: it has a POST /login endpoint then redirects on GET /user if auth succeeded. When I want to test for sql injection, sqlmap asks me if I need to follow the redirect. Should I say no to that or just no to the "rensend data to new location"? Thank you for your time.

Comment: No.. `redirect is a result of a POST request. Do you want to resend original POST data to a new location? [Y/n] y` means that it was redirected from login page A, to login page B.